# Adding Environment Variables

Tags: terminal, bash

I can't understand the 3rd line in these instructions, found [here](https://github.com/theeko74/pdfc)

> 1. Install dependency Ghostscript. On MacOSX: `brew install ghostscript`
> 2. Create a symbolic link if you want to run it everywhere in bash `ln -s pdf_creator.py pdfc`
> 3. Add in PATH environment variable On MacOSX: `echo export=/absolute/path/of/the/folder/script/:$PATH >> ~/.bash_profile`

What path are they talking about?  The path where the ghostcript is?  I don't know where that would be.  When I ran echo export=/absolute/path/of/the/folder/script/:$PATH in terminal, nothing happened to the bash profile.

---

Update

- Placed the folder `pdfc_master` which contains the file `pdf_compressor.py` in  `/users/bobsmith/codes/pdfc_master/pdf_compressor.py`
- Run `ln -s /users/bobsmith/codes/pdfc_master/pdf_compressor.py pdfc`
- Run `echo export=/users/bobsmith/codes/pdfc_master/pdf_compressor.py/:$PATH >> ~/.bash_profile`

I now have the following syntax on my bash_profile

```
export=/users/bobsmith/codes/pdfc_master/pdf_compressor.py/:/Users/bobsmith/codes/venv/bin:/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:/Users/bobsmith/Applications/miniconda3/condabin:/Users/bobsmith/.pyenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/applications/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/PycharmProjects/book/superlists/chromedriver:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

That looks wrong to me.

So I then ran in terminal:

```
pdfc /users/bobsmith/downloads/montale_eng3.pdf 0 /users/bobsmith/downloads/montale_eng2.pdf
```

And I got the error pdfc not found.  I would think that `pdfc` would have to be somewhere in my bash_profile but it is not.

Comment: Have you tried homebrew? 
It's just easier to install and update packages such as Ghostscript.

Comment: I have ghostscript installed.  My problem is with understanding the termanal syntax

Comment: see updated answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is the path where you have created the `pdfc` symbolic link.

The command you ran was incomplete - you need to first replace `/absolute/path/of/the/folder/script/` with the actual path to the `pdfc` symbolink link. In addition you must use the full command including `>> ~/.bash_profile` in order to actually get something saved in the bash profile.

Also, the 3rd line you quote is just wrong (also in Github itself), it should be

```
echo 'export PATH="/absolute/path/of/the/folder/script/:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

As you have already run the wrong command you'll need to edit your `.bash_profile` manually (e.g. with `nano`) to fix the wrong definition. Either source `.bash_profile` afterwards or open a new Terminal tab/window to load the new value.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand step 2.  Am I supposed to create a python file named `pdf_creator.py`?  If so what is the py file supposed to be composed of?

Comment: pdf_creator.py is the program, you're trying to install. You download that file from the page in question. Then they describe how to make it easier to run that program by creating a shorthand "pdfc" to run the program without having to type the full path and filename.

Comment: Can't I just write the correct syntax in the bash_profile directly on the txt file?  If I wrote the wrong definition then what is the right definition?  Also, not familiar with nano.  In short, what needs to be written in the bash_profile?  What symbolic links need to be formed?

Comment: @bobsmith76 The line in `.bash_profile` currently starts with `export=/users`, you need to change this to `export PATH=/users`. `nano` shows a little help at the bottom when you start it which should make clear how to use it and save the file at the end.